# How to access to input values created dynamically?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have created a method in my HomeController called Media that receives a number, according to this number my application create "n" quantity of inputs. 
The problem that I have is that I must to get values of "n" quantity of inputs to calculate arithmetic average of numbers entered. This is my **HomeController:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Media.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Media()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Media(int numero) {
             String elements = null;
             //elements= "<form action="Media" method='post'>";
            for (int i = 1; i <= numero; i++) {
                elements += "<input type= 'text' id='n"+i+"'"+"name='n"+ i + "'>" +""+"</input><br/>";
            }
            ViewBag.elements = elements + "<button id='btnCalcular'>Calcular media</button>";
                //"<button type="submit" id="button" name="button" action="Media" >Enviar</button> </ form > ";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is my cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Media";
}
    <form action="Media" method="post">
        <h2>Media de n números</h2>
        Ingrese el número de elementos:<br />
        <input type='text' id='numero' name='numero' />
        <button type="submit" id="button" name="button" >Enviar</button>
    </form>

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.elements)
```

**This is my result:**

[image: This is my result]

**Do you know any manner to access to that values?** Any help is really appretiated.

Comment: Access in what way? If you want to process them using C# then you need to send the values to the server, probably using AJAX or you can calculate them on the client. Either way you need to use Javascript to do this.

Comment: I need to get values entered in inputs to compute a average in my controller. @Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities. One of them is use JavaScript to read all values:

```js
function getValues() {
    const values = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
        .filter(a => /^n[0-9]{1,}$/.test(a.getAttribute('id')))
        .map(a => a.value)
        .join(',');
    console.log(values);
    // TODO Make some operation like ajax
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1">
<input type="text" id="n2">
<input type="text" id="n3">
<button onclick="getValues()">Post</button>
```

Other way is storing some reference into form and process in backend:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Media";
}
<form action="Media" method="post">
    <h2>Media de n números</h2>
    Ingrese el número de elementos:<br />
    <input type='text' id='numero' name='numero' />
    <button type="submit" id="button" name="button" >Enviar</button>
</form>

<form action="Test" method="post">
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.elements)
    <!-- store amount of elements -->
    <input type="hidden" name="myControl" value="@ViewBag.n" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Media(int numero) {
     // (...)
     ViewBag.n = numero;
     // (...)
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Test(int n) {
     // Example of how read posted values
     for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         var valueN = Request.Form["n" + i.ToString()];
     }
 }
```